# angularjs ui router : nested views and nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to understand nested views concept.
Based on the example provided in their documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

```
//home.html
<body>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="settings"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

I have `settings.html` which has a check box. If it's checked it will load in the view(not named) the advanced settings template if not it will load the basic template

```
//settings.html
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="change()"  ng-model="advancedSettings" />
<div ui-view></div>
```

so far I have defined something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    views: {
      'header': {},
      'settings': {
           templateUrl: 'settings.html'
       },
      'content': {},
    }
  })
```

since I have 2 templates `basicSettings.html` and `advancedSettings.html` that I need to load in the view from settings.html based on that checkbox, I thought I have to declare something like this:

```
.state('settings@home.basic',(){
    templateUrl: 'basicSettings.html'
});
```

but it's not working, instead I receive a lot of errors on console. How is the best way to implement this, without removing names from homepage views(header,settings,content), also how do I change the view based on the check box?

Thanks

Comment: bdw its should be `.state('settings@home.basic',{
    templateUrl: 'basicSettings.html'
});` removed `()` from state code

Comment: @PankajParkar I know that's not correct , I just wanted to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrDPSdoWXeD8SogNSnnE?p=preview)

Solution here could be with states defined like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'header': {
          template: "This is HEADER"
        },
        'settings': {
          templateUrl: 'settings.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        },
        'content': {
          template: "This is CONTENT"
        },
      }
    })
    .state('home.basic', {
      url: "/basic",
      templateUrl: 'basicSettings.html'
    })
    .state('home.advanced', {
      url: "/advanced",
      templateUrl: 'advancedSettings.html'
    })
```

we have parent state "home" and two children. These are triggered on change by **`'HomeCtrl'`**, e.g. like this:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
    function($scope, $state) {

      $scope.advancedSettings = false;

      $scope.change = function(){
        var childState = $scope.advancedSettings
          ? "home.advanced"
          : "home.basic";
        $state.go(childState);
      } 
}])
```

So, based on the setting, the view target "settings" and its **`ui-view=""`** (unnamed one) is filled with a child state - basic or advanced

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrDPSdoWXeD8SogNSnnE?p=preview)